# Jquery - Smooth/Fade Image Source Swap on imagemap?

Tags: jquery, image, transition, fade, imagemap

I am using the following code:

-Jquery:

```
jQuery(function(){
$("map.mainnav area")
  .on("mouseenter", function(){
     $("#menu_img").attr("src", $(this).data("menu-src"));
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function(){
     $("#menu_img").attr("src", $("#menu_img").data("menu-src"));
  });

});
```

on this HTML:

```
<nav>
<img id="menu_img" src="images/menu/menu_00.gif" alt="Navigation Menu" width="450"   height="900" usemap="#Map" class="centerimg" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_00.gif">
<map name="Map" class="mainnav">
  <area class="one" shape="rect" coords="55,26,269,69" href="#statement" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_01.gif">
  <area class="two" shape="rect" coords="234,112,361,159" href="#skills" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_02.gif">
  <area class="three" shape="rect" coords="129,213,339,256" href="#education" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_03.gif">
  <area class="four" shape="rect" coords="122,332,370,378" href="#experience" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_04.gif">
  <area class="five" shape="rect" coords="203,444,391,495" href="#portfolio" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_05.gif">
  <area class="six" shape="rect" coords="163,550,323,592" href="#contact" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_06.gif">
  <area class="seven" shape="rect" coords="4,688,436,833" href="#home" data-menu-src="images/menu/menu_07.gif">
</map>
</nav>
```

The idea is that hovering over the imagemap area switches the source of the image. That part works just fine. What I am wondering is, how can I make this transition smoother or fade in and out on mouseenter/mouseleave, instead of happen instantly, i.e fade in the new source while fading out the old? Is that even possible? All of the image fades I have come across require stacking the images on top of each other, and then animating opacity, which I am looking to avoid as there are so many of the images. Is there another solution, preferably utilizing the code I already have? If not, what would be the smartest (or a smarter) way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this plug in that has solved all my issues with my image maps:

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?what.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$("map.mainnav area")
  .on("mouseenter", function(){
     $("#menu_img").hide().attr("src", $(this).data("menu-src")).stop().fadeIn(200);
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function(){
     $("#menu_img").hide().attr("src", $("#menu_img").data("menu-src")).stop().fadeIn(200);
  });

});
```

Comment: Ok, got this working, but it causes an unsightly flash of white in between the two.  The image does fade in and out but it is not smooth, is there anyway to fade out the hide?

Comment: Solved the white flash by setting the background image of the div to be the default image,  but the transition back to the original source doesn't fade, it still just "snaps" back.  Any Ideas?

Comment: adding fadeOut seems to break the functionality entirely